# Flutter - Running flutter fails, Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml", Update - (OS Error: Access is denied. , errno = 5)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I just solved all the necessary dependencies.

```
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.7.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)
```

Now when I try running the flutter app on Android Studio I get this.

```
A:\Project\flutter_app>flutter run
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Running "flutter packages get" in flutter_app...
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\".
pub get failed (66)
```

Does anyone know what to do to resolve this issue?

[**Update 2 hours later**]

I deleted flutter and reinstalled in *C:\flutter* using the git repo 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Now the error I am getting is this

```
A:\Project\flutter_app>flutter run
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Running "flutter packages get" in flutter_app...
Cannot open file, path = '.\pubspec.lock' (OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5)
pub get failed (66)
```

**Update:** I tried using verbose when running *flutter packages upgrade -v* and got this

```
C:\flutter\flutter_app>flutter packages upgrade -v
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
[  +31 ms] executing: [C:\Users\Nick\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +76 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +1 ms] origin/beta
[        ] executing: [C:\Users\Nick\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +45 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] beta
[        ] executing: [C:\Users\Nick\flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +38 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +9 ms] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ] executing: [C:\Users\Nick\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +38 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] 3b309bda072a6b326e8aa4591a5836af600923ce
[   +7 ms] executing: [C:\Users\Nick\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[  +37 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[   +1 ms] 9 days ago
[        ] executing: [C:\Users\Nick\flutter\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[  +41 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[   +1 ms] v0.7.3-0-g3b309bda0
[ +170 ms] Running "flutter packages upgrade" in flutter_app...
[  +10 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\flutter_app\] C:\Users\Nick\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat --verbosity=warning --verbose upgrade --no-precompile
[+16555 ms] Cannot open file, path = '.\pubspec.lock' (OS Error: Access is denied.
[   +1 ms] , errno = 5)
[  +46 ms] Running "flutter packages upgrade" in flutter_app... (completed)
[  +15 ms] "flutter upgrade" took 16,687ms.
pub upgrade failed (66)

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:26:3)
#1      pub (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:170:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      pubGet (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:104:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      PackagesGetCommand._runPubGet (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/packages.dart:59:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      PackagesGetCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/packages.dart:82:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:356:18)
#6      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#9      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#10     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#11     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#12     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#13     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#14     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#15     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#16     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#17     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#20     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#21     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Created GitHub issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21495

**Update**: Not much has improved

@pskink asked me to create a new app in an empty directory while using verbose

**Output:**

```
C:\flutter>flutter create flutter_app -v
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Multiple output directories specified.
Try moving -v to be immediately following create

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:26:3)
#1      CreateCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/create.dart:106:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:356:18)
#3      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#6      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#8      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#9      Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#10     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#11     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#12     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#13     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#14     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#17     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#18     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Comment: did you create your app with `flutter create flutter_app`? what files do you have in `A:\Project\flutter_app`?

Comment: Did you check the working directory actually contains a `pubspec.yaml`? I have seen several similar reports but no one was willing to help to invistigate closer so far.

Comment: @pskink I created the flutter app with android studio and ran it on the same platform. I still got the same error

Comment: so what files do you have in that folder?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes I do have pubspec.yaml in my project directory

Comment: @pskink 

A:\Project\flutter_app>ls 

README.md  android  flutter_app.iml  flutter_app_android.iml  ios  lib  pubspec.yaml  test

Comment: OK tried to upgrade? I mean: `flutter upgrade`

Comment: The weird thing is ```C:\``` in `Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\".`. What kind of drive is `A:\`? Is there something special about it? Can you try creating the project on a normal local disk instead?

Comment: C:>flutter upgrade

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Upgrading Flutter from C:\Users\Nick\flutter...
Already up-to-date.

Comment: @GunterZochbauer I partitioned my hard disk that way

Comment: @GunterZochbauer I am going to do exactly that now

Comment: ok so now can you run `flutter doctor`? did `flutter upgrade` succeed?

Comment: @pskink flutter was up to date

Comment: @pskink on running flutter doctor everything is successful            


• No issues found!

Comment: @pskink I have updated the question and shown the output for that. I am going to create a new flutter app in C and see if it makes any difference

Comment: `Cannot open file, path = '.\pubspec.lock' (OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5)` looks like your current user doesn't have write permissions in the project directory.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try to create completely new project: `flutter create another_flutter_app`? run it in `A:\Project` folder

Comment: created a project in all directories. I'm getting the same new error

Comment: Cannot open file, path = '.\pubspec.lock' (OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5)

Comment: Do you think it could be a problem with git? Everytime I type a command I get fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: I had already done that before just in case. I have updated the output

Answer (score 3):

Don't copy `.packages` over from one machine to another. (It should be in `.gitignore` if using git.)

Instead, run flutter packages get on the mac, and it will recreate `.packages`.

(Don't copy `.flutter-plugins either`.)

1. Delete `.packages`
2. Delete `pubspec.lock`
3. Run below command shown in image

[image: Run below command shown in image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is caused by and outdated Git client.

Please ensure you only have one Git client in your `PATH` and that it is in a recent version.

Comment: C:\>git --version
git version 2.18.0.windows.1

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a Git 1.9.0 around anymore?

Comment: Yes. I uninstalled git, downloaded the new version, and installed it from scratch.

Comment: And what about msysgit?

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution. When I run the same command on Power Shell as an administrator it doesn't show any error.

```
PS C:\flutter\flutter_app> flutter packages get
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Running "flutter packages get" in C:\...                    16.1s
PS C:\flutter\flutter_app> flutter packages upgrade
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Running "flutter packages upgrade" in C:\...                86.9s
```

Answer (score 0):

kill dart.exe, try run

if still error,
after kill, reopen android studio as admin

Answer (score 0):

Delete app/.packages file from your project and use flutter upgrade to get packages again.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was related to my antivirus program. It worked when I uninstalled the block. Maybe it will help. I wish everybody good work

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened with me. But in my case I had set the property of the project folder to hidden. When I set that to unhide it started working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).